# Vertical Bar Showing Under Images?

Tags: html

I'm trying to add a few images to my site but for some reason vertical bars are showing under and to the right of the images.

Here's my website URL: http://bit.ly/Lcspfp

The problem images are the brand logos at the bottom of the page.

Here's the code im using to display the brand logos:

```
<ul id="brands">
<li><a><img src="images/brand1.png" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="images/brand2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="images/brand3.png" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="images/brand4.png" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="images/brand5.png" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="images/brand6.png" alt="" /></a></li>
<li class="last"></li><p>
</ul>
```

Here's an image of the images with the vertical bars that I dont want there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIBI2.png

Comment: because you have styles applied to the <a> and <img>

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS rule:

```
ul#brands a {
    background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete this CSS-rule :

```
background: url(../images/links_separator.gif) no-repeat 100% 50%;
```

It creates those vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 644 of your styles.css file to the following:

```
.footer ul a { padding-right:5px; margin-right:3px; }
```